# How can I stop cURL from using 100 Continue?

Tags: php, jquery, curl, proxy

So, long story short, I have an AJAX application that uses MVC Web API as the back end. The client however calls from a different domain and uses a PHP proxy file to get around cross-domain request issues.

However, using the PHP proxy, the Web API responds to certain requests with a `100 Continue` HTTP header and any requests that get this back take excessive time to complete (we're talking up to 2 mins or so) and can also return a non-valid response.

This [appears to be a known issue with cURL](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/php-and-curl-disabling-100-continue-header/) and the workaround is commonly cited as inserting the below line to remove the expect: 100 header in the cURL request

Unfortunately, the solution seems to be elusive for me:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$headers_new = "";
foreach($headers as $title => $body) {
    $headers_new[] = $title.": ".$body;
}
//$headers_new[] = 'Expect:';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_new);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') );
```

This code works but removes all the other headers (which isn't workable for me as I'm using HTTP basic auth headers to authenticate with the API).
You may also notice I tried adding the `Expect:` to the existing headers, but this didn't help me either.

How can I maintain the existing headers, but also prevent cURL from expecting a 100 continue?

Comment: `getallheaders()` does not do what you seem to think it does. It gets the request headers that were sent to you, not the request headers that curl will use. You should only need the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') );` line - remove everything else from the above code and it should work.

Comment: DaveRandom - actually that's exactly the intention - I'm taking the request headers and passing them on to the API (they include the HTTP Auth stuff). The problem is that cURL will _add_ the `Expect: 100` to these headers.

Comment: Referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964687/how-to-handle-100-continue-http-message) could you try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);`? Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is, this isn't classed as an error - it isn't actually failing!

Comment: Even [the authors of curl think this behaviour (of libcurl) is not good](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2017-07/0013.html).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670008/how-to-disable-expect-100-continue-in-libcurl-using-c-code

Answer (score 22):

Using `$headers_new[] = 'Expect:';` does work *unless* the `$headers_new` array contains a string that is `'Expect: 100-continue'`. In this case you need to remove it from the array otherwise it will be expecting the 100 continue (logically).

Because in your code you use [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/getallheaders) and you're not checking if it contains an `Expect: 100-continue` header already so this probably is the case in your case.

Here is a summary for the general situation (and the script that created it):

```
PHP Curl HTTP/1.1 100 Continue and CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

GET request ..........................................: Continue: No
GET request with empty header ........................: Continue: No
POST request with empty header .......................: Continue: Yes
POST request with expect continue explicitly set .....: Continue: Yes
POST request with expect (set to nothing) as well ....: Continue: Yes
POST request with expect continue from earlier removed: Continue: No
```

Code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.iana.org/domains/example/');

function curl_exec_continue($ch) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result   = curl_exec($ch);
    $continue = 0 === strpos($result, "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a");
    echo "Continue: ", $continue ? 'Yes' : 'No', "\n";

    return $result;
}

echo "GET request ..........................................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "GET request with empty header ........................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('hello'));
echo "POST request with empty header .......................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect: 100-continue';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "POST request with expect continue explicitly set .....: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect:';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "POST request with expect (set to nothing) as well ....: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

unset($header[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "POST request with expect continue from earlier removed: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the script, Hakre. Since I needed this for HTTP PUT, I extended it a bit with the following results:

```
GET request ..........................................: Continue: No
GET request with empty header ........................: Continue: No
POST request with empty header .......................: Continue: Yes
POST request with expect continue explicitly set .....: Continue: Yes
POST request with expect (set to nothing) as well ....: Continue: Yes
POST request with expect continue from earlier removed: Continue: No
PUT request with empty header ........................: Continue: Yes
PUT request with expect continue explicitly set ......: Continue: Yes
PUT request with expect (set to nothing) as well .....: Continue: Yes
PUT request with expect continue from earlier removed : Continue: No
DELETE request with empty header .....................: Continue: Yes
DELETE request with expect continue explicitly set ...: Continue: Yes
DELETE request with expect (set to nothing) as well ..: Continue: Yes
DELETE request with expect continue from earlier removed : Continue: No
```

Here's the script:

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init('http://www.iana.org/domains/example/');

function curl_exec_continue($ch) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result   = curl_exec($ch);
    $continue = 0 === strpos($result, "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a");
    echo "Continue: ", $continue ? 'Yes' : 'No', "\n";

    return $result;
}

// --- GET

echo "GET request ..........................................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "GET request with empty header ........................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

// --- POST

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('hello'));
echo "POST request with empty header .......................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect: 100-continue';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "POST request with expect continue explicitly set .....: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect:';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "POST request with expect (set to nothing) as well ....: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

unset($header[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "POST request with expect continue from earlier removed: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

// --- PUT

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, TRUE);

$header = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "PUT request with empty header ........................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect: 100-continue';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "PUT request with expect continue explicitly set ......: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect:';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "PUT request with expect (set to nothing) as well .....: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

unset($header[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "PUT request with expect continue from earlier removed : ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

// --- DELETE

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");

$header = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "DELETE request with empty header .....................: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect: 100-continue';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "DELETE request with expect continue explicitly set ...: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

$header[] = 'Expect:';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "DELETE request with expect (set to nothing) as well ..: ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

unset($header[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
echo "DELETE request with expect continue from earlier removed : ", !curl_exec_continue($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing the header 101 continue use this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
```

Comment: It works even for command line curl.