# libcurl delays for 1 second before uploading data, command-line curl does not

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, mongoose-web-server

I am using libcurl to send an API command to a local service (i.e. on 127.0.0.1).

The program is intended to replace a shell script (that uses the `curl` program.)

Everything is working, except that there is a 1-second delay somewhere, i.e 1 second elapses from the time I call `curl_easy_perform()` to when my read callback function is first called.

The C program is using these options (error checking & callback code omitted):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:12345/x");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, (long)getLengthOfCommandObject());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, &myReadFunction);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &myWriteFunction);
```

But if I run `curl` from the shell like this:

```
$ curl --data-binary '<command>' http://127.0.0.1:12345/x
```

it sends the request immediately, without suffering from the 1-second delay.

What might be causing the delay, and is there an option I can set to prevent it?

---

**Edit** The server is based on [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)

Comment: Did you try executing your binary with _strace_ ? it could show any delay at program execution. Man page of strace has many time related options.

Comment: @VoidPointer, strace did not reveal anything relevant, but I found the cause. See my answer.

Comment: Even the authors of libcurl [think this behaviour of libcurl is a mistake](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2017-07/0013.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason for the delay was:

- libcurl was [sending an `Expect: 100-Continue` header](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2004-08/0002.html)
- The server (which is based on [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)) is [not configured to send `100 Continue` responses automatically](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-users/92fD1Elk5m4).
- libcurl waits up to 1 second for this response.  If it does not receive it after this time then it proceeds to send the request body anyway.

A solution on the client side is to disable the `Expect` header like so:

```
headers = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Expect:");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
// ...
result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_slist_free_all(headers);
```

[Equivalent fix for PHP client](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/php-and-curl-disabling-100-continue-header/) and [related PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158675/how-can-i-stop-curl-from-using-100-continue)

Comment: Just out of interest, how do you check that an `Expect: 100-continue` header is being sent by libcurl? I'm having similar delays, maybe this is the problem...I'm just not sure how to check if this is being sent within my request header. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not an Answer, but shows where the problem is happening in `curl`. I had the same problem with `libcurl` versus `Civet` which is based on `mongoose`.

I had the same problem and did run `strace` to attempt to debug.  This is the output from `strace` (with a timestamp in seconds on each line). The issue is that there is a sequence of `poll( ...events=POLLIN...)` calls that block for a total of 1000 milliseconds (1+98+1+900) after the header is sent, before the body is sent.  You can see the gap in timestamps from 17.935024 to 18.931842.

```
17.934881 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
17.934898 fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
17.934916 fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
17.934934 connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(37034), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
17.934952 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}])
17.934970 getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
17.934988 getpeername(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(37034), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
17.935006 getsockname(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46830), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
17.935024 sendto(5, "POST /foo/1/bar HTTP/"..., 168, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 168
17.935042  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
17.935060  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1)     = 0 (Timeout)
17.935078  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
18.029421  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 98)    = 0 (Timeout)
18.029518  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
18.030576  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1)     = 0 (Timeout)
18.030681  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
18.931571  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 900)   = 0 (Timeout)
18.931642  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
18.931698  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 2, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
18.931726  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=5, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}])
18.931842 sendto(5, "{\"foo\":[{\"bar\":\"A\",\"e"..., 1642, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 1642
```

I had the same problem with both the command-line `curl` as well as with `curl_easy_perform`, but I did not have the problem using a different REST client such as Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @finnw's answer and the discussion here (https://groups.google.com/g/mongoose-users/c/92fD1Elk5m4?pli=1), I was able to patch CivetWeb to support the `100-continue` feature with the following (see `#ifdef DEXPECT_100_CONTINUE_FIX`).

```
void
CivetServer::getPostData(struct mg_connection *conn, std::string& dst)
{

    struct mg_request_info *ri = mg_get_request_info(conn);
    assert(ri != NULL);
    CivetServer *me = (CivetServer*) (ri->user_data);
    assert(me != NULL);
    mg_lock_context(me->context);
    CivetConnection &conobj = me->connections[conn];
    mg_lock_connection(conn);
    mg_unlock_context(me->context);

#ifdef EXPECT_100_CONTINUE_FIX
    const char * expect_str = mg_get_header(conn, "Expect");
    if (expect_str)
    {
        printf("CivetServer::getParam, Expect:%s\n", expect_str);
        if (strcmp(expect_str,"100-continue") == 0)
        {
            mg_printf(conn, "%s", "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("CivetServer::getParam, Expect: blank\n");
    }
#endif
```