# cURL slow starttransfer_time

Tags: php, performance, curl

Good Day!

cURL is acting very slow when requesting a page. I know its not the page requested, because  the page returns in the browser instantly.

2 things I've noticed

- The starttransfer_time is regularly almost 20
- The local_port seems to change every time. Is that normal?
- Occasionally, cURL will respond instantly

I have the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Echoing curl_getinfo() gives me the following

```
[url] => http://127.0.0.1:80/wpengine/?json=t
[content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[http_code] => 302
[header_size] => 215
[request_size] => 64
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 17.238
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 221
[speed_download] => 12
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 221
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 17.238
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
[primary_port] => 80
[local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
[local_port] => 51875
[redirect_url] =>
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to figure out what is going on?

Here are a few lines from the Apache access log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2013:12:01:22 -0500] "GET /wpengine/?json=t HTTP/1.1" 302 221
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2013:12:01:12 -0500] "GET /community HTTP/1.1" 200 6266
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2013:12:01:22 -0500] "GET /public/js/jquery.js?b=10 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: If you're running this locally, what server do you have set up? Can you check the server logs?

Comment: @r3mus I am running Wamp with Apache. I edited my post to include a few lines from the access log

Comment: Curious if maybe CURL is trying IPv6 first, and failing to resolve? Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );`

Comment: Hmm, that did not make a difference. I find this very puzzling. Could it have something to do with sessions as it is on the same domain? Just a shot in the dark...

Comment: Not really sure, but looking at your logs, once CURL actually *hits* the server, it's super fast. Any way you can try this on a public server somewhere to eliminate the localhost variable?

Comment: Sure! Ill give it a shot, and let you know what happens. Thanks helping!

Comment: @remus option helps me with connection by OAuth protocol

Answer (score 5):

This is mostly because of the `Expect: 100-continue` header CURL send to the server when it handles large POST data, and the server just happened not support this feature. You can confirm by add `-vv` for `curl` command line and see the outputs.

To solve this, you can either

1. fix your server to support `Expect: 100-continue` header, or
2. force curl not to send it by add `-H "Expect:"` option (in php, you can refer to this answer: [How can I stop cURL from using 100 Continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158675/how-can-i-stop-curl-from-using-100-continue)).

Links about `Expect: 100-continue`:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3
https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/59909909--Expect-100-Continue-Issues-and-Risks

Answer (score 2):

I've found a similar issue when hitting Google Analytics' MP API ... the starttransfer time is consistently 1.0 seconds plus a tiny amount, from which I infer there is a 1 second delay somewhere, I am guessing in cURL. It's not using CPU at my end, and I somehow doubt Google is putting in the delay... otuput from curl_getinfo() ...

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.google-analytics.com/collect
    [content_type] => image/gif
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 388
    [request_size] => 201
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.021528
    [namelookup_time] => 8.7E-5
    [connect_time] => 8.8E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.000324
    [size_upload] => 1736
    [size_download] => 35
    [speed_download] => 34
    [speed_upload] => 1699
    [download_content_length] => 35
    [upload_content_length] => 1736
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.002496
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: Yeah, a quick command line script using lwp-request (starting a new Perl interpreter for every POST) is miles faster than cURL looped in one PHP process.

Comment: I found out a way to fix this, at least for my needs ... I was passing the above argument list to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS expecting it to generate a urlencoded post body, but in fact it generates multipart. In order to get it to send a plain URLencoded POST you have to encode the body parameters yourself and pass a ready-to-use string. For some reason, the multipart process has a one second delay, the plain POST works at full speed.

Comment: YES. Even though I don't understand why multipart takes so long to start, it worked, delay has gone! You should really update your answer with this info

Answer (score 2):

One of the comments by @brandonscript in this thread helped me solve the problem.

His answer:

> Curious if maybe CURL is trying IPv6 first, and failing to resolve?
>
> Try adding **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );**

My problem was the opposite, I had to set the following option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6 );
```

Thank you, wonderful people.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution for me. The destination server _only_ had IPv6. This immediately removed the delay on `starttransfer_time`

Answer (score 0):

I used **Fiddler** app from **Telerik** to debug connections, and did not find any problem, I think it may be related to web server child process workers.
To debug using Fiddler paste the following line before `curl_exec($ch)`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

Thank you all for the pointers