# How to setup default "Expect" header for curl

Tags: curl, http-headers

Can I setup my (CLI) `curl` to either not set *"Expect: 100-continue"* or to set it to *"Expect: "* for my command-line browsing?

I've ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538763/162070) issue with GCE Load balancer returning 502 for curl because it's confused by `Expect: 100` and breaks, and now I have to manually set it up on every request. (Well, not manually, I have aliases for the stuff I test frequently, but that's not the point.)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `~/.curlrc` file and put your default options in that. Described in the man page section for [-K, --config](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-K).

A default option to switch off the Expect: header could be:

```
header = "Expect:"
```