# Force tomcat to use only HTTP 1.0 or ignore Except header

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, curl, http-headers

Is there a possibility to force tomcat to ignore "Expect" header or to use only HTTP 1.0?

I am sending curl request `curl POST -vv 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/test' -d "@requests/test.xml" -H "SOAPAction: abc/test" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8"` and curl adds by default "Expect" header which causes server waits for another request which never come.

Tech stack: Springboot 2.1.3.RELEASE, Tomcat 9.0.16

I cannot modify clients and to their requests empty header "Expect:".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get Tomcat to respond only with an HTTP 1.0 response.  That would be a protocol violation.  If server gets an HTTP 1.1 request it must either respond with a HTTP 1.1 compatible response, or signal that it can't with a `505 HTTP Version Not Supported` error.

Likewise, I don't think there is a way to get Tomcat to ignore a (well-formed / non-empty) Expect header.  That would also be a protocol violation.

(While it is possible in theory for a server to violate the spec, I couldn't find a way to configure Tomcat to do that.  Obviously you could download the Tomcat source code and modify it, but then you have the problem of maintaining your "fork".)

---

So what are the alternatives:

1. The HTTP spec says that server *must* ignore an Expect header in an HTTP 1.0 request.  So you could add the `--http1.0` option to the `curl` command.
2. The `curl` command uses a defaults file - `~/.curlrc` - to get default overrides for various things.  You could add an empty default for the Expect header into this file; see [How to setup default "Expect" header for curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045248/how-to-setup-default-expect-header-for-curl).

However, I think you may be worried unduly:

1. If you are worried that this will slow up the client (`curl`), don't.  By default it only waits for 1 second for the `100 Continue` response.  (And I don't think that is what you are talking about ...)
2. If you are worried that this might tie up server side resources (in Tomcat), I can't see how that could be significant.  The Tomcat server will timeout and close a client connection if there is no activity.  This should deal with a `curl` command that sends the initial request but doesn't follow up.